# I can use form to upload pictures on my site,but when I upload mp3 files, it doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I use form in asp.net mvc site to upload files, the code goes like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddFiles", "Management", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>    
               <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="file" id="fileToBeUploaded" name="fileToBeUploaded"/>            
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    }
```

I can use this to upload pictures and text, but when I try to upload mp3 and wmv files, it can't direct to AddFiles action.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Are these files' sizes are more than 4MB? It's the default file size in the configuration file. If that's the case you have to change it to upload larger files.

**Update:**

There is Web.config file in your project.Find this line there:

```
<system.web>
```

Add your custom maxRequestLength by adding this line under it:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400"/>
```

This means a request can be long as 102400 KB or 100 MB. You can type it and see Intellisense help you.